# Using module variable in template file

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I use drupal 6 and book module. I want to change book content type's design. So I need to use a module's variable in my tpl file. There is a variable in book-navigation.tpl.php which is called $next_title. How can I use it in my template file?

I read lots of about preproccess function but I couldn't see a real example.

Comment: Have a look at [`template_preprocess_book_navigation()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/template_preprocess_book_navigation/6), that's where the `$next_title` variable comes from

Comment: Ok I know that but I am a newbie. I need guidance. I cloned this function and changed it's name to book_preprocess_node. Variables came to node page but all of them is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use template_preprocess_node:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6

In your theme's template.php file, do this:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_node().
 */
function MY_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->type == 'book') {
    $variables['next_title'] = 'My custom next title';
  }
}
```

Flush Drupal's theme registry after adding that function, then you should be all set.

Alternatively, you can use **MY_MODULE_preprocess_node** if you want the function to be in a custom module.

Then in your book-navigation.tpl.php (you can either use the default one, or add this file to your theme's directory and make modifications), you just need to use:

```
<?php print $next_title; ?>
```

Also check out the [template_preprocess_book_navigation()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/template_preprocess_book_navigation/6) function:

And be sure to use the [devel module's](http://drupal.org/project/devel) dpm function on $variables to easily see what is available, like so:

```
dpm($variables);
```

The [book_next()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/book_next/6) function may be of use in your node preprocessor. Sometimes you have to use preprocessors to dynamically inject variables into tpl.php files. Because the $variables is different for every preprocessor and every tpl.php file.

Comment: First thanks for reply. I know this method. But I want to make it dynamic. Normally $next_title has a different value for each book node. And I want to use it in node-book.tpl.php

Comment: $variables['next_title'] = 'My custom next title'; this is static for every book node.

Comment: There are some variables is book-naviagtion.tpl.php and I want to print them seperately in node-book.tpl.php. I'll we crazy there is no solution for this

Comment: There is a function which is called book_next() can we use it?

Comment: I use devel module and list variables. But I couldn't achieved. I need some more help.